Removal of NaCl form sodium hydroxide (NaOH) solution
We have a plant for liquefaction of sodium hydroxide (NaOH) flakes to concentration of about 50%, but there is unfavorable NaCl content about 200 ppm, we need to reduce the concentration of NaCl to under 50ppm. Is there any cost-effective and economical solution for such problem?

Providing summary of the prior topic review allows responders not to provide you what you already know or what you could easily find. CH SE is sometimes abused as a free topic review service where a user could quickly find it on his/her own. Sometimes even on this site.// Review the guide How to ask and Asking FAQs to prevent clarification requests, objections,  downvoting or closure.

Use a Quaternary ammonium ion exchange resin, that reacts with all anions like Cl- and transforms them into OH- ions.

dear @Maurice I do not know about the process and application of such material. Besides, if we use such resin as a separator or decomposition medium, does it work like water softener resin tank? I mean I do not know about regeneration procedure of resin granules once it became saturated. Could you please help me with this?  Thanks

@Maurice The other question of mine is finding a calculation method for volume of required resin and also, the velocity of the fluid in the reaction.
